# Manipulate/Recode Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Working on some simple data manipulation in Pandas and uncertain how to do something along the lines of the logic defined below. I'm trying to change values in Column C based on values in Column A in this sample idea. Suggestions?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
if df['A'] < 2:
    df['C'] = "Small"
else:
    df['C'] = "Big"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditions work different in pandas. You can try

```
import numpy as np
df['C'] = np.where(df.A < 2, 'small','big')
df
```

Output

```
   A  B      C
0  0  5  small
1  1  6  small
2  2  7    big
3  3  8    big
4  4  9    big
```